# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No more parsing elements

Tags: java, json

I have angularjs frontend and java backend, in development it works, but not in production,
same code, same database.
I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No more parsing elements.

I noticed that in development some json fields are empty strings like "field" : "", but in production the same field is null like "filed" : null, and another field is an object like "field" : {}

Both development and production are debian linux, nginx 1.16.1, same angularjs code and java code.

What could make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Solved updating java version to jdk8u242-b08 in production server.